# Phone language has been changed from setting but still app shows localised string data

Tags: android, kotlin, locale, lokalise

I have a functionality in my app where I do the langugae change using Lokalise SDK.
For example I have created a string for english, germen, french. If I update the my phone language from english to germen then application landuage also change to german. Now I update the languge to english in my phone setting so default is set to english now. But when I open the app(even after kill or clearing the data) then still it shows app language as german.

```
Lokalise.init(this, AppConstants.lokaliseToken, AppConstants.projectId)
    Lokalise.setLocale(Locale.getDefault().language)
```

I have used above code to get the default language from my locale. And I even getting the locale as per desired. But this does not reflect to my app.